# .next(".myClass") Not Working Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I don't know how to access the value that I want I've tried a lot of things but I don't know how to find my value.
Here is my HTML:

```
<table class="liste">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Coordonnées</th>
            <th>Diplômes</th>
            <th>Profil associé</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="groupe" colspan="5">2014-2015            
                <button class="copyMails" title="Copier les adresses emails">
                     <img src="/images/picto/action_dupliquer.png" alt="">
                    Copier les adresses emails
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="lstMails" value="myText">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Coordonnées</th>
            <th>Diplômes</th>
            <th>Profil associé</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="groupe" colspan="5">2014-2015            
                <button class="copyMails" title="Copier les adresses emails">
                     <img src="/images/picto/action_dupliquer.png" alt="">
                    Copier les adresses emails
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            BLABLABLA
        </tr>
        <tr>
            BLABLABLA
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="lstMails" value="myText2">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$("body").on('click', ".copyMails", function() {
    console.log($(this).parent().parent().parent().next('.lstMails').val());
});
```

I've tried with and with parent with more and less etc. But I don't know how to do this.
I want to access the next .lstMails when I click on the button .copyMails

Comment: Make working fiddle for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to navigate parent `tr` then use [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to point to next `tr` then you can use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Use

```
$("body").on('click', ".copyMails",function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('.lstMails').val());
});
```

*Update*

```
$("body").on('click', ".copyMails", function() {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr:has(.lstMails)').find('.lstMails').val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem is that the .lstMails isn't allways in the next tr, I've edited my html to show an exemple.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find the next `tr` sibling and then the `lstMails` element inside it

```js
$("body").on('click', ".copyMails", function() {
  $('#log').html($(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr:has(.lstMails)').first().find('.lstMails').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="liste">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Actions</th>
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Coordonnées</th>
      <th>Diplômes</th>
      <th>Profil associé</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="groupe" colspan="5">2014-2015
        <button class="copyMails" title="Copier les adresses emails">
          <img src="/images/picto/action_dupliquer.png" alt="">Copier les adresses emails
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="lstMails" value="myText">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Actions</th>
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Coordonnées</th>
      <th>Diplômes</th>
      <th>Profil associé</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="groupe" colspan="5">2014-2015
        <button class="copyMails" title="Copier les adresses emails">
          <img src="/images/picto/action_dupliquer.png" alt="">Copier les adresses emails
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BLABLABLA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BLABLABLA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="lstMails" value="myText2">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Your code is getting the `tbody` ancestor of the clicked button, then trying to find the next sibling which has class `lstMails` - that is not what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem is that the .lstMails isn't allways in the next tr, I've edited my html to show an exemple.